# Error: Assignment under multiple single edges is not supported for synthesis

Tags: verilog

It is a four bit counter T flipflop design. `Tflip` module is used for each bit.

```
   module Tflip (q,t,clk,rst);
    output q;
    input t,clk,rst;
    reg q; //q output must be registered 
    always @ (posedge clk or negedge rst)
     if (rst <= 0)
       q <= 1'b0;
     else
       q <= t^q; // it is made up with X-OR gate.
  endmodule
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Synthesis tools require specific coding patterns, but you do not have a conventional reset condition.  Change:

```
if (rst <= 0)
```

to:

```
if (!rst)
```

Perhaps your synthesis tool is confused because your code reads as:

> if reset is less than or equal to 0

Synthesis tools also recognize the following patterns for active-low reset conditions:

```
if (~rst)
```

and:

```
if (rst == 0)
```